# If Checkbox Value in LocalStorage is Equal to "true" getItem Checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Question...

I was able to set my checkboxes to "true" if checked, however, i am persisting data in localStorage which gets the item value using 'getItem'. The problem is, is im having trouble writting the function to check if the value equals 'true'... and if it is == to true, mark the check the checkbox.

**This is how my localstorage saves the checked items:**

[image]

Perfect but how to getItem with the boxes checked?

**My function for my inputs look like:**

```
     if (localStorage.getItem('contractor')) { 
         contr100.value = localStorage.getItem('contractor'); }
```

This works fine for my basic inputs and the data comes back without issue. However, trying to bring back the checkboxes "checked" seems to be my challenge.

Using getItem, the checkboxes come back empty. The inputs work fine but can't populate the checked checkboxes again upon return to the form.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use JS to set the value to checked if the value in localstorage is set to true?

Comment: I've already done this... i now need to be able to populate the checkbox on return to the form. It works for inputs using getItem but the checkboxes come back empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (localStorage.getItem('contractor') == 'true') { 
        document.getElementById('checkbox').checked = true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('checkbox').checked = false;
    }
```

Comment: This looks so promising and it just seems like it should work, but after implementing it... moving to a different page, and coming back to my form... its still not checked!

Comment: what happens if you check it manually, change the page and coming back? same problem?

Comment: if i check it manually by using: <scipt>document.getElementById("contractor").checked = true;</script>  the checkbox stays...but there is no value in localstorage..its empty!

Comment: Changed your single quotes in the ID check to double and it works like a charm! Thanks a million @brauchle_andi